# In Flutter how to sync app data with google drive

Tags: database, flutter, google-drive-api, synchronization, backup

I am using sqflite local db. i want to sync the data with the google drive. i have created a hidden app data folder in google drive and successfully uploaded data to that folder also able to retrieve the data. but i am trying to achieve incremental update to the file. i have unsynced data in db can i upload only unsynced data to the db in google drive rather than uploading the entire data as db.Any other suggestion how to update the data in google drive rather than replacing the data .Thanks in advance

Comment: you can create a file and update a file.  if the file has changed you will need to upload it again.  Im not sure i understand the question

Comment: I could do that but size of the backup increase day by day. Replacing the old backup may not be an efficient solution. An incremental backup will solve that but i haven't found any solution how to achieve that. Can i use a google sheet as a database and insert data into it?

Comment: I don't think drive supports incremental update.   Yes you could use sheets as a database.  Why not firebase though?